# BasicNetwork.performRequest - Unexpected response code 400 in android 6.0.1 but not on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-volley

I try below code on my android samsung and it gives error. (I want to get channel property)

```
String URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?hl=tr_TR&part=snippet&q=" + channel + "&type=channel&safeSearch=moderate&maxResults=1&key=xxxxxx";
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject snippet = item.getJSONObject("snippet");
                String channelId = snippet.getString("channelId");
                //getVideo(channelId);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    //  Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());
    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

);
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

it gives this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cocuklaricin.junioryoutube, PID: 13820
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:334)
        at com.cocuklaricin.junioryoutube.MainActivity$1$2.onErrorResponse(MainActivity.java:127)
        at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:617)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:104)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 45
E/Volley: [4518] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?hl=tr_TR&part=snippet&q=Cartoon Network Türkiye&type=channel&safeSearch=moderate&maxResults=1&key=xxxx
```

But when I try it on my emulator , it works fine.

What is the difference? How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the code for getVideo(channelId) method?

Comment: I updated my question. I remove getvideo code and it gives same error

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

Comment: @blackapps what is this meaning

Comment: `at com.cocuklaricin.junioryoutube.MainActivity$1$2.onErrorResponse(MainActivity.java:127)`

Comment: Look at line 127.

Comment: is it showing any toast while crashing ?

Comment: Ok it causes crash but When I close that codes it does not crash but it gives same error --- error code 400

Comment: Add `if ( error==null) return;` as first statement there.

Comment: Where do you get eror code 400?

Comment: I get it from :  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

Comment: What does 400 mean?

Comment: it means : BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?hl=tr_TR&part=snippet&q=Cartoon Network Türkiye&type=channel&safeSearch=moderate&maxResults=1&key=xxx

Comment: No. You got an error code from the webserver. A http error. What does 400 mean?

Comment: I do not know , it gives error on my phone but not on emulator,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to check `null` before use `error.getMessage()` like below

```
   new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         if(error.getMessage==null){
                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to retrieve data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                         else{

                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }

                });
```

also don't forget to convert it into String like `error.getMessage().toString();`

**UPDATE**

Make sure your `url` should not contain any blank space so
 IMO you may replace any space in input `channel` with `%20` like `Cartoon%20Network%20Türkiye`
then this `url` will valid.

Comment: It does not the main problem,
problem is :  BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for googleapis.com/youtube/v3/… Network Türkiye&type=channel&safeSearch=moderate&maxResults=1&key=xxx

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar oh ok IMO you may replace any space in input `channel` with `%20` like `Cartoon%20Network%20Türkiye`

Comment: ok thanks my man it saves my life :) pls update your answer like that then I tick as correct

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar ohh gr8! happy to help you please check updated answer...!